# Invalid Foreign Key value in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am getting an invalid foreign key value and I cannot figure out what it is, here is the error.

Executed as multiple statements.

STATEMENT 1:

> DATABASE  completed. 0 rows processed. Elapsed time = 00:00:00.047

STATEMENT 2:

> Insert Statement failed.  Failed [2700 : 23000] Referential constraint violation: invalid foreign key value.

This happens when I try to insert:

```
insert into SALE values (1,30.45,'2020-12-31','VMBNH',1,1);

into the SALE Table
```

Here is the table, and I am also including the inserts that I already put on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE EQUIPMENT_DETAIL 
(   
    EquipDetailID INT NOT NULL,   
    Make VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    Equipment_Type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    Model VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (EquipDetailID) 
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER 
(
    CustID INT NOT NULL,   
    CustName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,   
    CustCategory VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (CustID)
);    

CREATE TABLE EQUIPMENT 
(   
    SerialNo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  
    LastInspectedDate DATE NOT NULL,   
    DateMade DATE NOT NULL,  
    EquipDetailID INT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (SerialNo),   
    FOREIGN KEY (EquipDetailID) REFERENCES EQUIPMENT_DETAIL(EquipDetailID) 
);

CREATE TABLE SALE 
(   
    SaleTransID INT NOT NULL,   
    Price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,   
    Sale_Date DATE NOT NULL,   
    SerialNo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    CustID INT NOT NULL,   
    SRepID INT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY(SaleTransID),   
    FOREIGN KEY (SerialNo) REFERENCES EQUIPMENT(SerialNo),   
    FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustID),   
    FOREIGN KEY (SRepID) REFERENCES SALES_REP(SRepID)
);

CREATE TABLE RENTAL 
(   
    Price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,   
    Rental_Date DATE NOT NULL,   
    RentTransID INT NOT NULL,   
    SerialNo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    CustID INT NOT NULL,   
    SRepID INT NOT NULL,   
    PRIMARY KEY (RentTransID),   
    FOREIGN KEY (SerialNo) REFERENCES EQUIPMENT(SerialNo),   
    FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustID),   
    FOREIGN KEY (SRepID) REFERENCES SALES_REP(SRepID)
);

CREATE TABLE SALES_REP 
(   
    SRepID INT NOT NULL,   
    SRepLName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,   
    SRepFName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    Rank_ID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,   
    Mentors_SRepID INT,   
    PRIMARY KEY (SRepID),  
    FOREIGN KEY (Mentors_SRepID) REFERENCES SALES_REP(SRepID) 
);



insert into EQUIPMENT_DETAIL values (1,'CFT','Drill','B123');
insert into EQUIPMENT_DETAIL values (2,'CFT','Hammer','B124');
insert into EQUIPMENT_DETAIL values (3,'MKT','Saw','M123');
insert into EQUIPMENT_DETAIL values (4'MKT','Wrench','M124');
insert into EQUIPMENT_DETAIL values (5'SNP','Flat Head','S123');

insert into CUSTOMER values (1,'Jim Halpert','A');
insert into CUSTOMER values (2,'Michael Scott','B');


insert into EQUIPMENT values ('KDJHS','2021-01-12','2010-11-11',1);
insert into EQUIPMENT values ('VMBNH','2021-03-05','2007-12-12',2);
insert into EQUIPMENT values ('QIEIR','2021-03-05','2007-12-12',3);
insert into EQUIPMENT values ('PTPYO','2021-03-05','2007-12-12',4);
insert into EQUIPMENT values ('AGSGD','2021-03-05','2007-12-12',5);
```

Comment: I don't see an insert into SALES_REP, having SRep_ID = 1.....

Answer (score 0):

I had to drop the foreign key constraint from SALE (SRepID)